# SQL matching parts of a string in a column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-like, concatenation

```
TABLE 1                        TABLE 2  
**ID  NAME**                   **ID  NAME**
  2   Mcdonalds NY               2   McDonalds
  3   KFC                        3   Burger king
```

I have already joined the tables linking them via their ID numbers. I am creating an exception report. What I'm struggling with is a query that will leave out Names that are almost similar (Mcdonalds NY - Mcdonalds) but select the obvious (KFC - Burger king).

I tried using `where Table1.Name like Table2.Name or Concat`

Comment: 1. Add a tag of your DBMS, and if possible, version 2. You'll have to define "almost" similar. 3. It's still unclear what you are trying to do. You want lines from table 1 that do not exist in table 2....in "almost similar " name?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quite simple way to check for and rule out those that are almost equal

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.name, '%') AND  t1.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',t2.name, '%')
```

Comment: The OP wants an *exception* report, so I think s/he wants the ones that don't match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for that. Somehow I forgot it along the way.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH TAB1(ID , NAME ) AS(
SELECT 2,'Mcdonalds NY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'KFC' from dual  )
--Select * from tab1;
,
TAB2(ID , NAME ) AS(

SELECT 2,'McDonalds ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'Burger king' FROM DUAL  )

select * from (
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME ,UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(A.NAME, B.NAME) similar
FROM TAB1 A
JOIN TAB2 B ON A.ID= B.ID
)

where similar >= 75
```

for more info https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/utl_match-string-matching-in-oracle

Comment: does utl_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity work on sql server or only oracle

Comment: You could use `SELECT VALUES` to shorten your example code.

Comment: I saw the comment about the question was regarding sql server too late. This it oracle code. If it exists for sql server I do not know sorry

Comment: I do not see how I could use SELECT VALUES here. please enlighten me.

Comment: @CheriChoc The whole example can be reduced into: `SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(A.NAME, B.NAME) similar
FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (2,'Mcdonalds NY'), (3,'KFC')) tab1(id, name)) a
JOIN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (2,'McDonalds '), (3,'Burger king')) tab2(id, name)) b ON a.ID = b.ID`

Comment: nice one @slartidan did not know that one, It does not work in oracle though.

Comment: But the question is tagged with "sql-server" so we are talking about the tsql dialect, right?

Comment: Since this answer is for the wrong DBMS it might be better to delete it.